# In jQuery how do you trigger function when dom changes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, function, dom

I am using a jQuery plugin that adds background--dark background--complex class to text to contrast it from a background, and this changed during scrolling to background--light background--complex for example. I would need to add class to overlay id (dover=dark overlay) (nover=no overlay) (lover=light overlay) depending on what class the plugin has added to the text. I am really not advanced with jQuery, Im not asking you to do it instead of me but you would save me a lot of struggle and I would understand it better...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    if(jQuery( "#globaltext" ).hasClass( "background--dark background--complex" )){
        jQuery( "#overlay" ).addClass( "dover" );
    }else{
        jQuery( "#overlay" ).addClass( "nover" );
    }
});
```

Comment: need more detail. The code you have posted doesn't change the DOM. It checks to see if #globaltext has a class and then does something. Where are you changing the DOM and what event do you want to trigger the function?

Comment: @garek007 the DOM change takes place inside this file. I am looking for a solution similar to MutationObserver, but that I can not get running. 
[link] (https://github.com/kennethcachia/background-check/blob/master/background-check.js)

Comment: I still more information. I cannot read through that file to figure out what you need. Can you explain what you are trying to do and all steps involved?

Comment: @garek007 The plugin adds classes to #globaltext which are _background--dark background--complex_ , _background--light background--complex_ . I have made an overlay div above the background image with the 3 classes, dover, lover, nover. I would need a solution that checks if the current class on #globaltext is _background--dark background--complex_ or _background--light background--complex_ and depending on that add .dover/.lover/.nover to the #overlay. It takes a few seconds for the plugin to recognize add classes and the code I posted fires instantly. Something that monitor changes to a div.

Comment: So is the code you posted above working for you? 

Secondly, you need a function to fire AFTER "dover" or "nover" classes are added?

Comment: @garek007 I need an event that fires my code when changes happen to <div #globaltext .class_changes_here>

Comment: jquery doesn't have anything that will help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another solution.
you dont need jQuery, just javascript in enough

HTML :

```
<div id="classList">my Colors</div>

<button onclick="changeClass('red')">red</button>
<button onclick="changeClass('blue')">blue</button>
<button onclick="changeClass('yellow')">yellow</button>
```

CSS:

```
.red{
  color:red;
}
.blue{
  color:blue;
}
.yellow{
  color:yellow;
}
```

for javascript part 1: create EventListener

```
// create custom EventListener for just attribute
function attributeEventListener(target, attr, fun){
  target = document.querySelector(target);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      // just looking for our attribute
      if (mutation.attributeName == attr){
        fun();
      }
    });    
  });

  // configuration of the observer:
  //just looking for attributes
  var config = {attributes: true};

  // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
  observer.observe(target, config);
}
```

part 2 - you need to use it like that :

```
new attributeEventListener('#classList','class', function(){
  console.log('changed ...');
});
// first parameter is target (css selector)
// second parameter is attribute name (for your case is class)
// third parameter is your function when event called ...
```

part 3 - change class

```
function changeClass(color){
      var target = document.getElementById('classList');
      if (target.className != color)
        target.className = color; 
    }
```

**see my code here** : https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/qmGEgm

MutationObserver documents: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

**Broswer Support:** just modern browsers support mutationobserver